# Angular2 Qunit code coverage

Tags: typescript, angular, qunit, remap-istanbul

is there any good handy code coverage measurement tool/framework which I can easily incorporate to measure the code coverage for Angular2-TypeScript code with tests written in QUnit?

I see few such framework like [remap-istanbul](https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul), [blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/) etc., but these frameworks threw exceptions at all the import statements which are from Angular2 libraries (e.g. angular2/core or @angular/core)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using karma?

PS: `angular2/core` has been move to `@angular/core`

PPS: Would have written this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation.. .